# What is the better alternative for If else in implementing the logic in a program? | C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods

I am building an Automative application that lets the user select the options from the check boxes etc. and the price is shown at the end for charges.

Problem is that the way I completed this application is awkward. For example, see my if else statements they don't cover every aspect of the decision.

For example, here is the part of my code

```
private decimal RushesMethod(out decimal radiatorRush_var, out decimal transmissionFlush_var, out decimal both_var)
        {
            radiatorRush_var = 0m;
            transmissionFlush_var = 0m;
            both_var = 0m;

            if (radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                radiatorRush_var = 30.00m;  
            }

            else if (transmissionFlushCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                transmissionFlush_var = 80.00m;  
            }

            else if (radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked && transmissionFlushCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                radiatorRush_var = 30.00m;
                transmissionFlush_var = 80.00m;            
                both_var = radiatorRush_var + transmissionFlush_var;
            }

            return both_var + transmissionFlush_var + radiatorRush_var;


        }
```

What if the user selects the `radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked` option and some other options ONLY which are not it this method let's say `oilChangeCheckBox.Checked` then how will I cover all of that decision. It will be a way too lengthy to make if else statements for all because who knows what the user selects.

Here is what happens if I select all the options then it doesn't show the correct price.

[image]

Here is the FULL application CODE:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Automative_APP
{
    public partial class automativeForm : Form
    {
        public automativeForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ClearOilLube()
        {

            oilChangeCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            lubeJobCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }

        private void ClearFlushes()
        {
            radiatorRushCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            transmissionFlushCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }

        private void ClearMisc()
        {
            inspectionCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            replaceMufflerCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
            tireRotationCheckBox.CheckState = CheckState.Unchecked;
        }

        private void ClearOthers()
        {
            partsTextBox.Text = "";
            laborTextBox.Text = "";
        }

        private void ClearFees()
        {
            serviceLaborAnsLabelBox.Text = "";
            partsSummaryAnsLabelBox.Text = "";
            taxPartsAnsLabelBox.Text = "";
            totalFeesAnsLabelBox.Text = "";          
        }






        private decimal TotalCharges()
        {
            decimal rushesVar = RushesMethod();
            decimal oiLAndLubeVar = OilLubeCharges();
            decimal miscVar = MiscMethod();
            decimal partsLaborVar = PartsLaborMethod();
            decimal storeTaxCharges = TaxCharges();
            decimal totalSum;
            decimal totalSum1;

            totalSum1 = (rushesVar + oiLAndLubeVar + miscVar);


            totalSum = (rushesVar + oiLAndLubeVar + miscVar + partsLaborVar);


            partsSummaryAnsLabelBox.Text = partsLaborVar.ToString();

            partsSummaryAnsLabelBox.Text = partsTextBox.Text;

            serviceLaborAnsLabelBox.Text = "Total Services fee is " + " " + totalFeesAnsLabelBox.Text + " " + "and Labor amount is" + " " + laborTextBox.Text;

            taxPartsAnsLabelBox.Text = storeTaxCharges.ToString();

            return totalSum;

        }





        private decimal TaxCharges()
        {
            const decimal PARTS_TAX_VAR = 0.6m;
            decimal storeTax;
            decimal taxCal;


            storeTax = decimal.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
            taxCal = PARTS_TAX_VAR * storeTax;

            return taxCal;


        }



        private decimal PartsLaborMethod()
        {
            decimal PL=0m;
            decimal labor;
            decimal totalPL = 0m;

            PL = decimal.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);         
            labor = decimal.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);

               totalPL= PL* labor;

               return totalPL;
        }



        private decimal MiscMethod()
        {
            decimal valueTotal2 = 0m;

            if (inspectionCheckBox.Checked && replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked && tireRotationCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal2 += (15.00m + 100.00m + 20.00m);
            }

            else if (inspectionCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal2 += 15.00m;
            }

            else if (replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal2 += 100.00m;
            }

            else if (tireRotationCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal2 += 20.00m;
            }

            return valueTotal2;


        }






          private decimal RushesMethod()
        {
            decimal valueTotal = 0m;

            if (radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal += 30.00m;  
            }

            else if (transmissionFlushCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotal += 80.00m;  
            }

            else if (radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked && transmissionFlushCheckBox.Checked)
            {

                valueTotal += (80.00m + 30.00m);
            }

            return valueTotal;


        }


        private decimal OilLubeCharges()
        {

            decimal valueTotalOL=0m;

            if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked && lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotalOL += (26.00m + 18.00m);

            }

            else if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotalOL += 26.00m;

            }

            else if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
            {
                valueTotalOL += 18.00m;
            }

            return valueTotalOL;            

        }


        private void partsSummaryLabelBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void taxPartsLabelBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close(); //close the form
        }

        private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           decimal totalStore= TotalCharges();

           totalFeesAnsLabelBox.Text = totalStore.ToString();


        }

        private void clearButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClearOilLube();
            ClearFlushes();
            ClearMisc();
            ClearOthers();
            ClearFees();
        }
    }
}
```

> EDIT:

Here is what the question says,

```
The application should have the following value-returning methods:
• OilLubeCharges —Returns the total charges for an oil change and/or a lube job, if any.
• FlushCharges —Returns the total charges for a radiator flush and/or a transmission flush, if any.
• MiscCharges —Returns the total charges for an inspection, muffler replacement, and/or a tire rotation, if any.
• OtherCharges —Returns the total charges for other services (parts and labor), if any.
• TaxCharges —Returns the amount of sales tax, if any. Sales tax is 6% and is charged only on parts. If the customer purchases services only, no sales tax is charged.
• TotalCharges —Returns the total charges.
The application should have the following void methods, called when the user clicks the Clear button:
• ClearOilLube —Clears the check boxes for oil change and lube job.
• ClearFlushes —Clears the check boxes for radiator flush and transmission flush.
• ClearMisc —Clears the check boxes for inspection, muffler replacement, and tire rotation.
• ClearOther —Clears the text boxes for parts and labor.
• ClearFees —Clears the labels that display the labels in the section marked Summary
```

> Finally, I did it by using the **@OmegaMan's** solution. I wanted to
>   post the changes so that it can help anyone

I made changes to the TotalCharges() method. Compare the earlier one and this.

```
private decimal TotalCharges()
        {

            decimal total = 0.0m;

            if ( inspectionCheckBox.Checked)

            total +=  15.00m;

            if (replaceMufflerCheckBox.Checked)

                total += 100.00m;

            if (tireRotationCheckBox.Checked)

                total += 20.00m;

            if (oilChangeCheckBox.Checked)

                total += 26.00m;

            if (lubeJobCheckBox.Checked)
                total += 18.00m;

            if (radiatorRushCheckBox.Checked)

                total += 30.00m;

            if (transmissionFlushCheckBox.Checked)

                total += 80.00m;

            return total;
```

I also made changes to the Calculate button CLICK EVENT HANDLER:

```
private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

           decimal totalStore= TotalCharges();
            decimal taxCharge = TaxCharges();

           totalFeesAnsLabelBox.Text = (totalStore + taxCharge).ToString();
            taxPartsAnsLabelBox.Text = taxCharge.ToString();
            partsSummaryAnsLabelBox.Text = partsTextBox.Text;
            serviceLaborAnsLabelBox.Text = "The Total Service charges are" + totalStore + "and Labor is " + laborTextBox.Text;
```

Rest of it is same and the logic worked successfully. Thanks to all of you who contributed.

Comment: You need to have business rules for all the combinations. If you don't have, you need to disable some UI parts when the user selects something. So that you allow only valid combinations.

Comment: It would have been great if I could have reduced the UI parts, but I can not because we are bound to make this application only which has these all parts. So, the only way is to make the `if` statement of every combination possible whether it is from across different methods?

Comment: Do you mean that you want an single method to calculate the sum of the prices (total price) based on all the checked checkboxes. So if a checkbox is ticked, we add the price, else we don't ?

Comment: I wish I could, but again we are bound to include these all methods. in order to complete this application.

Comment: You can do all this price calculation using one method only. Instead of all these if else statements. I'll post an answer in a couple of minutes.

Comment: your method may not be returning what you expect.  it is returning `0+0+30` (`30`) `0+80+0` (`80`), or `110+80+30` (`220`).  You might want to review your logic, and in that you may see a way to reduce the number of evaluations.

Comment: @Claies yeah! I know that's why I asked this question.

Comment: @GhostRider check my answer below.

Comment: also, returning a total at the same time as returning the passed in variables as `out` may be reduntant, and zeroing passed in variables before sending them back as `out` may cause bugs, especially if those variables are never actually used in the calculations.

Comment: What you want to do is roughly create a *Finite State Machine* where every state **centralizes the summation for each localized process**. Then a separate total function will add the costs together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sum up and centralize the totaling operation in a separate method and check the state each of the Checkboxes while doing the sum:

```
public decimal TotalCosts()
{
    decimal total = 0.0m;

    if ({Oil Changed Checked})
       total += {Oil Cost};

    if ({Transmission checked})
       total += {Transmission total};

    if ({Repair Clutch})         
       total += {Clutch Cost}; // Maybe call a separate method ClutchTotal()?

     ... { Do this for all check boxes }

    return total;
}
```

---

Don't attempt to individually add things together for disparate operations (as you did with the `both_var = radiatorRush_var + transmissionFlush_var;` , that is your confusion.

---

**Finite State Machine**

I mentioned a *finite state machine* logic which is useful in organizing any code.

Think of a vending machine, it has to take all different types of coins as well as dollar bills and it has certain states before it can provide product. **By mapping out all states** and then **centralizing the code** to handle each state, that will go far in make the code bug free and maintainable.

If one adds a dime into the machine, the state goes from `Welcome` into summing up the current coins and dollars but not providing the product. That state is true until total > cost, then the `Vend` state is hit which distributes the product. It doesn't go back to the `Welcome` state until it finishes a final step of `provide any monies if overpayment`.

By setting up states one can organize one's code to handle all situations as you are seeing in your app.

Comment: Thanks, I'm finding your answer little easy to digest. I have one confusion that My question require that every method should return the value if there are any, but you said to check all that in a separate method total, but then what will be other methods returning?

Comment: @GhostRider If there are other methods that do individual logic summations for specific totals, say for a `ClutchTotal` which requires specific summations, then `ClutchTotal` should only return a cost for clutch operations right? But if `ClutchTotal` requires a service other than clutch be required, then change the target checkbox state for that other service to true (in `ClutchTotal`),  but don't *sum* it up in the `ClutchTotal` only *fully* sum **all** up in the `TotalCost` method as shown above.

Comment: Brother, your logic is good, Kindly check my TotalCharges() method I'm calling all the other methods from there and storing them in variables to be displayed, if that is wrong then where should I call them.

Comment: @GhostRider I believe you are on the right track by re-organizing the code. I gave a quick glance at what you have, but I think if you keep working towards such centralization of code (no repeats of totaling) and calling the methods, that is the route.

Comment: Thanks, man I did it the way you told me. You are a life savor. I edited the question and put what I did to solve the problem. I gave you the credits there also. Thanks once again

Comment: Hey, bro! I have one question where are other methods using. I even deleted one of the methods for example, `RushesMethod()` and the application was even working fine. It's because we did all the if statements in the TotalCharges() method so now there is no need for the other method. But, I want other methods to do some work. In simple words I didn't call any of the methods except TaxCharges() , TotalCharges()

Answer (score 3):

To minimize this, you can create a mapping of Checkbox to decimal (Price). When you need to calculate the price related to checked checkboxes you can do it using one line only.

So first, create a mapping variable and populate it at some point (for me i chose form load - You can do it in the constructor after `InitializeComponent();` :

**Note : Rename the checkboxes to your valid ones.**

```
List<KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>> checkboxPriceMapping;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkboxPriceMapping = new List<KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox1, 26.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox2, 18.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox3, 15.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox4, 100.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox5, 20.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox6, 30.0m),
        new KeyValuePair<CheckBox, decimal>(checkBox7, 80.0m),
    };
}
```

Then, this is a simple method to calculate the total price of the checked controls:

```
private decimal CalculateTotalPrice()
{
    return checkboxPriceMapping.Where(x => x.Key.Checked).Sum(x => x.Value);
}
```

Comment: I actually like your answer, but I think the OP is firstly needing to understand how to organize C# code to handle the process; more than a better heuristic in summation. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I applied this business rule design to your problem using http://www.michael-whelan.net/rules-design-pattern/ and this is what I came up with. Using this method you could abstract each purchase case into its own "rule" and if you need to anything more complex based on the state of the order you can just add new rules or make changes to your existing rules.

I'd also recommend that you add a database of some sort to save your prices, tax percentage and whatever other numbers you may need to fumble around with in the future if you haven't already as well as to save any historical data.

### Interface

```
public interface IExpenseRule
{
    decimal CalculateExpense(Order customerOrder);
}
```

### Representing the Order State

This represents the state of our Order  and will be our source of truth for all our calculations. If in the future you need more properties for additional costs then they would be accessible from here. For example, if I wanted to add a car wash the I can add a car wash flag here or Enum if there are levels for the wash.

```
    public class Order
    {
        public bool HasOilChange { get; set; }
        public bool HasLubeJob { get; set; }
        public bool HasRadiatorRush { get; set; }
        public bool HasTransmissionFlush { get; set; }
        public bool HasInspection { get; set; }
        public bool HasTireRotation { get; set; }
        public bool HasMufflerReplacement { get; set; }
        public decimal PartsCost { get; set; }
        public decimal LaborsCost { get; set; }
    }
```

### Calculation of the Order

Here is where we apply the rules to our calculations. The constructor is where all the rules are added to the rule collection. The CalculateTotal iterates over the rules. A rule is only concerned with whatever item it has to calculate. Each rule's result gets added together to get the total. The `Sum` method is a Linq extension used to add the results of the rules together. You could use a for loop if you want instead.

```
public class OrderCalculator
{
    List<IExpenseRule> rules = new List<IExpenseRule>();

    //all your rules get added here
    public OrderCalculator()
    {
        rules.Add(new OilChangeRule());
        rules.Add(new LubeJobRule());
        rules.Add(new TireRotationRule());
        rules.Add(new TaxOnPartsRule());
    }

//Runs all your calculations and returns the total based on the rules you feed and your order state
public decimal CalculateTotal(Order customerOrder)
{
    var total = 0m;
    total = rules.Sum(rule => rule.CalculateExpense(customerOrder));
    return total;
}
```

}

### Example Rules

A couple examples of the rules in play. We if we have rules that are interdependent  I leave the rest as an exercise of the OP.

```
<pre><code>public class OilChangeRule : IExpenseRule
{
    public const decimal OilChangeCost = 26.00m;

    public decimal CalculateExpense(Order customerOrder)
    {
        return customerOrder.HasOilChange ? OilChangeCost : 0;
    }
}

public class LubeJobRule : IExpenseRule
{
    public const decimal LubeJobCost = 18.00m;

    public decimal CalculateExpense(Order customerOrder)
    {
        return customerOrder.HasLubeJob ? LubeJobCost : 0;
    }
}


public class TireRotationRule : IExpenseRule
{
    public const decimal TireRotationCost = 20.00m;

    public decimal CalculateExpense(Order customerOrder)
    {
        return customerOrder.HasTireRotation ? TireRotationCost : 0;
    }
}

public class TaxOnPartsRule : IExpenseRule 
{
    public const decimal TaxPercentageOnParts = 0.6m;

    public decimal CalculateExpense(Order customerOrder)
    {
        var taxOnParts = customerOrder.PartsCost * TaxPercentageOnParts;
        return taxOnParts;
    }
}</code></pre>
```

### What your Form code looks like after the refactor

Your applications logic should stay separate from any UI. The business logic can be put into its own dll and reused in whatever type of app you want after this. (Yes, this code could likely be simplified even further but I think this is fairly straight forward and clear.)

```
public Order BuildOrder()
{
    var currentOrder = new Order();
    currentOrder.HasOilChange = oilChangeCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasLubeJob = lubeJobCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasRadiatorRush = radiatorRushCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasTransmissionFlush = transmissionFlushCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasInspection = inspectionCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasMufflerReplacement = replaceMufflerCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.HasTireRotation = tireRotationCheckBox.CheckState;
    currentOrder.PartsCost = Decimal.Parse(partsTextBox.Text);
    currentOrder.LaborsCost = Decimal.Parse(laborTextBox.Text);
    return order;
}

private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var totalCalculator = new OrderCalculator();
   var partsCalculator = new PartsCalculator();
   var serviceCalculator = new ServiceCalculator();
   var order = BuildOrder();
   var totalCost = totalCalculator.CalculateTotal(order);
   var partsCost = partsCalculator.CalculateTotal(order);
   var serviceCost = serviceCalculator.CalculateTotal(order);
   //Do what you need to with the totals here;
   totalFeesAnsLabelBox.Text = totalCost.ToString();
}
```